# Excel - How To Extract Data From One Sheet To Format Into Another Sheet With A Repeating Template?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Using Excel I am attempting to extract data from one sheet into another that will format to a repeating template (In my case printable cards to add onto our clients products).

My "Pricing" sheet has 8 labels, like so:

- Serial No.
- Name
- Brand
- Our Cost
- Carpet Cost (Yard)
- Carpet Cost (Foot)
- Install (Yard)
- Install (Foot)

With this data I want to pull it into another sheet called "Print Off". I need to have this sheet populate a repeating template that pulls in the following based from the Serial No.:

- Brand
- Our Cost
- Carpet Cost (Yard)
- Carpet Cost (Foot)
- Install (Yard)
- Install (Foot)

The repeating template will need to be a standard business card size of 3.5(w) X 2(h).

*If I could get them to print side-by-side to not waste paper, this would be a plus!

Comment: Which part of this is giving you problems?

Comment: Hey Ted ~ The problem I am having is when I try to pull in the data from the "Pricing" sheet into the "Print Off" sheet using =VLOOKUP(lookup value, table range, column number, [true/false]). I have my fields defined in a Name Box called "newdata". Then from here I cannot find a solution to develop a repeating template. Thanks for reaching out so fast!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer with InDesign CS6 Data Merge. Below are the steps I took to accomplish this:

Excel > Export CSV > InDesign (CS6) > Data Merge to Custom Template > Save To PDF > Print Multiple Sheets

Data Merge can be found by clicking Window – Utilities – Data Merge (*Make sure you do not have any unused columns or rows, because it will not import over).

In my case I needed each to print out each card next to each other to save paper. I accomplished this by printing the PDF as multiple sheets. I clicked custom size and adjusted them to print side by side without altering the size dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not know which cells you have I will use my own.

On the Pricing sheet you have Serial No. in Cell A1. So on the Print Off sheet the Brand cell is A1 you will put in the cell of the Brand `=Pricing!$A$1`. This will pull the data from the Pricing sheet and place into the Brand Cell.

Then you repeat this for the other items you want and then you have a printable template.

Comment: I have this working, but if I can recall I did not go this route because I could not get the =Pricing!$A$1 fields to automatically repeat for the next card (I have a few thousand to go through). Do I have to then make a script to populate this for the next card?

Comment: I am attempting to run a macro to do this without any luck. Do you have any suggestions that I might be able to use?